# Write it in VB .NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, delphi

this is **Delphi 6** code :

```
Buf: array[1..5000000] of Char;
BufC: array[1..5000000] of Char;
```

how to write it in **VB.NET**?

this is why i need 'var' BufC (Delphi6):

```
var
i,ii: LongInt;
BitPenanda,inbuf,buflong,SameBit,ulang4,uu :integer;
SigmaMin:LongInt;
Save_Cursor:TCursor;
SigmaAscii: Array[0..255] of LongInt;

Begin
BufC[1]:='R';BufC[2]:='U';BufC[3]:='N';
for uu:=0 to 255 do
```

........................................................

Comment: Why don't you do it yourself? Stack Overflow is not a place to demand that others write code for you. If you don't know any VB.net then you need to learn some.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i've tried it.. I am not a professional in programming languages ​​and I am human being..That's why I ask and look for solutions, and I really appreciate everyone who has helped me and hope I can help them as well in several ways..

Comment: If you have tried, then you should show what you have tried.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there are still many things to be learned, & one of them as you say..Thank you Sir.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Buf(4999999) as Char
Dim BufC(4999999) as Char
```

Based on your edit:

```
Dim i,ii,SigmaMin as Long
Dim BitPenanda,inbuf,buflong,SameBit,ulang4,uu as Integer;
Dim BufC(4999999) as Char
//TCursor? 
Dim SigmaAscii (255) as Long;



For uu = 0 To 255
     BufC(0) = "R"
     BufC(1) = "U"
     BufC(2) = "N"
Next
```

The code above seems quite meaningless though, unless you have a typo?

Comment: `Char` is 16 bit in VB.net, 8 bit in Delphi 6. `Long` is 8 64 bit in VB.net, 32 bit in Delphi.

Comment: @user1831003 It's work.. :D thanks sir.. for a little correction, "[]" change it to "()"..

Comment: @liohardy .. is it a homework assignment? If yes, then my code is incorrect. Tell me the purpose of this code so I can properly guide you.

Comment: The loop performs 256 identical assignments. The loop is pointless. The compiler would be justified in removing it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I already wrote it's "quite meaningless" :)

Comment: @user1831003 yes sir, it's for my homework.."Algorithm Run Length" code in Delphi6..this is just beginning..Really? Wow..I really need it, because i am still very amateur..

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not know how it plays out later but I am sure, I will be able to finish it if I do not give up.. :)

Comment: @liohardy you need to make sure Integer, Long etc match to corresponding datatype in Delphi. Do you see what I mean? Just because it "works", it doesn't matter, it's correct. Just fix the datatypes and you might be good to go. Paste full original assignment on pastebin so we can take a look.

Comment: @user1831003 original assignment? did you mean the Delphi or VB?

Comment: @liohardy Delphi. As well as the assignment words, unless it only says "Convert it into VB.NET", lol.

Comment: @user1831003 [link](http://pastebin.com/iqDhwfFv) By the way sir, this is only partially, because if I put all of them, would be too much and confuse..

Comment: @liohardy It's too much already! lol... when is it due? I can help you with it but maybe during the weekend. Also, you copied-pasted code here all wrong. Now, the assignment makes more sense, lol.

Comment: @user1831003 lol..how stupid I am.. -_- ..btw, what is your email address? so, we can contact each other.. :) or you can email me 1st..